How do I acccess the Bright data proxies response headers
I am using Bright data as the proxy proivider along with python requests.session. I am directly making proxy requests to the proxy zones so it can randomly pick it up, now what I want is to know which IP it used, for that bright data provides response headers 'x-brd-ip' telling which ip was used, but this is not being recieved in the final response headers of the session requests, on using -v flag with curl, I found that during the connection phase of the request(), these responses were made, how do I extract those using the python requests
I tried using different libraries, like curl, httpx but none seem to be as convinent as requests

try this:
import requests

proxies = {
    'http': 'http://your_proxy',
    'https': 'http://your_proxy'
}

response = session.get('http://example.com', proxies=proxies)

ip_used = response.headers.get('x-brd-ip')
print(ip_used)

also if the above code doesn't work try to print the entire response headers with print (response.headers) then extract your ip address from it

Perhaps, You can use curl -i command
-i option will show response headers in output.
As a result, You can easily extract the IP Address you want from the output.
